# Does domain extension affect seo?

Tags: web, seo, rank

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask. However... does domain extension affect SEO rank? 
For example, I know that the extension .com means commercial, or .org means something non-commercial but how about SEO ranking stand-point?

.com vs .website vs .me vs .us vs .co

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO and likely belongs to other site like http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Side note: consider to read tag information on tags you've selected - SEO - http://stackoverflow.com/tags/seo/info...

Comment: OP posted it on [webmasters.se]: [Does domain extension affect seo?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/78965/17633)

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In this case the question has already been asked and answered there: [Does Google penalize sites on "commercial" country code domains such as .me or .tv?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2330/does-google-penalize-sites-on-commercial-country-code-domains-such-as-me-or)

Answer (score 0):

No not at all. Domain extension don't give a ranking boost. They are treated equally by default (at least in Google).

Answer (score 0):

No...
Domain extension doesn't affect your SEO score.
Based on your business type & category it is very important to know about the extensions and select the one which suits your business.